# get user password profile

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I have tried the link - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console and it works for me.
The problem is I am not able to get the password as user.PasswordProfile is null.
Please help.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you are able to fetch an existing PasswordProfile over the network once the user is created. The PasswordProfile property is for setting/creating a new PassworldProfile for a new User or existing User (i.e. updating).

Comment: Can the username and password be authenticated with the azure active directory via a console application with Graph API?

Comment: @AnjuE I have the same question. Did you figured out the issue?